# Testing a function which has a Promise and setTimeout, why is it timing out?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, timeout, settimeout

I'm trying to test a function that has `setTimeout` inside a promise. However it keeps timing out.

This is the function:

```
export const sleep = async (duration: number): Promise<void> => {
  await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    console.log("sleep end");
  }
};
```

And this is my test:

```
import { sleep } from "../../helpers/utils";

console.log = jest.fn();
jest.useFakeTimers();

test("calls sleep with correct argument and calls console.log", async () => {
  const NODE_ENV = "test";
  const SLEEP_DURATION = "100";

  process.env = { ...process.env, NODE_ENV, SLEEP_DURATION };

  const timeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(global, "setTimeout");

  await sleep(+SLEEP_DURATION);

  jest.runAllTimers();

  expect(sleep).toHaveBeenCalledWith(+SLEEP_DURATION);
  expect(timeoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(+SLEEP_DURATION);
  expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("sleep end");
});
```

The problem is that when I try to run this the test fails and gives this message:

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

I've tried `jest.setTimeout(10000)` which just throws an error of `Exceeded timeout of 10000ms ...`

Any idea as to why this is happening? Or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: When you `useFakeTimers`, the timeout callback will never be called right? So `await sleep(+SLEEP_DURATION);` will never resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that gets closer to what you're going for. Importantly, you can't `await` the resolution of the promise using fake timers or it'll never resolve. Instead, you can call assign the return value of the `sleep` function to a variable, then run the timers, then await the variable.

I also adjusted your `expect` statement for the timeout spy since it takes two arguments. Finally, I removed your expectationt that `sleep` gets called with the duration because you're literally doing that in the test, so it doesn't seem worthwhile to make that assertion.

```js
console.log = jest.fn();
jest.useFakeTimers();

test("calls sleep with correct argument and calls console.log", async () => {
  const NODE_ENV = "test";
  const SLEEP_DURATION = "100";

  process.env = { ...process.env, NODE_ENV, SLEEP_DURATION };

  const timeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(global, "setTimeout");

  const sleepFn = sleep(+SLEEP_DURATION);

  jest.runAllTimers();

  // Now that we ran timers we can await the promise resolving 
  await sleepFn;

  // timeout takes two arguments
  expect(timeoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.any(Function),
    +SLEEP_DURATION
  );
  expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("sleep end");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer, this is my first time using these jest timers so I definitely have some studying to do!